# Parse Inverse Expressions For Calculator

Tags: java, parsing, calculator

I have a calculator, but it only calculates 2 number, one operator equations, like 6 + 9 or 5 ÷ 40. How do you parse inverse expressions for a java calculator to do longer equations like 2 + 6 x 4 - 7? Or is there another way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform your equation to Reversed Polish Notation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

When you have a RPN expression it's easy to calculate the value.